# A question about coprime action on a 2-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

I'm stuck somewhere in the following problem in Isaacs Finite Group Theory [4D.4], I would appreciate if you could help:

**Problem:** Let $A$ act via automorphisms on $G$ , where $G$ is a $2$-group and $A$ has
odd order. Show that if $A$ fixes every element $x$ in $G$ such that $x^4=1,$ then  the action of $A$ on $G$ is trivial.

**My attempt:**

**Case 1**:In the case $G$ is abelian, the result follows from Fitting's theorem,
$G$ = $C_G(A)$ $\times$ $[G,A].$ Since $C_G(A)$ and $[G,A]$ has trivial intersection and $C_G(A)$ contains each element $x$ in $G$ such that $x^4=1,$ $[G,A]$ cannot have an element of order $2.$ But $[G,A]$ is a $2$-group and every nontrivial $2$-group has an element of order $2$. Therefore, it must be $[G,A ]= 1,$ and the claim follows.

**Case 2:** Let's use induction on $\vert G \vert.$ If $[G,A]$ is a proper subgroup of $G,$ then by inductive hypothesis $[G,A,A]=1.$ In a coprime action, it must be $[G,A,A]=[G,A]$, the result follows. Hence, we can assume that $[G,A]=G.$ How can I get the desired result from this point?

Thanks.

Comment: This follows from (g) of Exercise 4D.3. I would guess that that is how you are expected to do it!

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I came to the following conclusion:
We can certainly assume that G>1. Let's use induction on the order of G. If H is an  A-invariant proper subgroup of G , the inductive hypothesis guarantees that A acts trivially on H , and hence [H , A] = 1.  Now, if [G,A] is not trivial then by 4D.3 (g), x^4=1 for all x in G. Due to hypothesis given in the problem (A fixes every element x in G such that x^4=1) A fixes G. We get a contradiction. There it must be [G,A]=1. The result follows. 
Is there anything missing ?

Comment: Yes, that looks OK.